# HttpResponse Blob

Tags: angular, download, httpresponse

I have an application with Angular 13, where I make a POST request to the back, and I need to get the header, and get the Content-Disposition part, where the filename comes from.

**Therefore, I created the service as follows:**

```
downloadRelatorioArquivos(data: any): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
     return this.http.post<HttpResponse<Blob>>(`${this.API}/baixarExcel`, { ...data }, { responseType: 'blob' as 'json'});
}
```

**And in my component I call the service as follows:**

```
 onDownloadRelatorioArquivos() {
    this.loading = true;

    this.service.downloadRelatorioArquivos(this.form.value).subscribe({
      next: (res: HttpResponse<Blob>) => {
        console.log('dados responde blob');
        console.log(res.headers);
        this.loading = false;
        this.download(res, `RELATÓRIO_ARQUIVOS${this.form.value.data}.xlsx`);
      },
      error: () => this.loading = false
    });
  }

  private download(response: any, nomenclatura: string){
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = nomenclatura;
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
    a.click();
  }
```

However, when doing console.log(res.headers), it comes up undefined, as res already only brings the file for download.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `{ observe: 'response' }` to get the full HTTP response.

This is how your service method should look like:

```js
downloadRelatorioArquivos(data: any): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
  return this.http.post<HttpResponse<Blob>>(
    `${this.API}/baixarExcel`,
    { ...data },
    { responseType: 'blob' as 'json', observe: 'response' }
  );
}
```

Also change the way you're calling download():

```js
this.download(res.body,`RELATÓRIO_ARQUIVOS${this.form.value.data}.xlsx`);
```

Comment: I've done it this way too, and it actually brings me some information, but in the response header it has (Content-Disposition), which it doesn't. What I bring are just url, type, statusText, status, ok, headers(lazyInit, lazyupdate, normalizedNames), body(size, type)

Comment: so no filename in response ? you might wanna extract it from content-disposition by doing `res.headers.get('Content-Disposition');`  then maybe some regex to get the filename then pass it to the download method.

Comment: I already did this, and it comes as null.

Comment: It would make things super easier if you actually listed in your original question what you have tried, the response you're getting, and potentially a stackblitz if possible.